# initialRouteName is not taking correctly by using AsyncStorage in react native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I need to navigate based on the AsyncStorage values in react-native navigation. but its always taking me to the landing page even if i have values in AsyncStorage.

below what i have tried so far,

```
    function App(props) {
  const [storeId, setStoreId] = useState(null);

  AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEYS.LOCATION_ID).then((id) => {
    setStoreId(id);
  });

  const initialRoute = storeId && 'NfcScreen';
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName={initialRoute}
          screenOptions={!isTablet ? styles : ''}>
          {isTablet && (
            <Stack.Screen
              options={{headerShown: false}}
              name={appPages.locationIdentification}
              component={Locationidentification}
            />
          )}
          <Stack.Screen
            name={appPages.nfc}
            component={NfcPage}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
  </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
```

I have noticed first state returning null then its returning the asyncstorage value. because the state update slowly the locationIdentification page get rendered. is there any way i can try??

a help would be really appreciable. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Every setState action re-renders the page, so you need to access the latest state.
I think you should put your AsynacStorage code in an usseEffect and define the           initialRouteName value as a function

Update:
maybe it's late, but you could use navigation listeners

Comment: i did the same and that not resolving the issue @Jamal :(

Comment: According to its name, AsyncStorage has a small delay, because of that you update the state after routing, you should keep it till the state updates